# Is there any way of getting the audio level of an audio device using the AudioSwitcher.AudioApi?

Tags: c#, api, winapi, audio

Is there any way of getting the volume level of an audio device in C# using the AudioSwitcher.AudioAPI.

I'm able to set and get the MAX volume of the audio device using:

```
deviceName.volume;
```

But is there any way of getting the CURRENT volume of the audio device. E.g. there is a YouTube video playing and I want to get the percentage of the audio level (Like in windows)

I would like to use the same API already used (AudioSwitcher.AudioAPI) to keep the application light. But, if there isn't any other solution, I can use another API.

Comment: What if you have two YT videos open in the browser, and each of those players have different volume settings? It's perfectly possible and practically doable. And because this is practically and easily doable, there can therefore be no such thing as a "current" device volume aside from the actual device/application volume level, at least as web browsers are concerned...

Comment: What I ment was the master of the audio device. For example, I have a pair of headphones and a set of speakers. A youtube video and spotify is playing through the headphones. I'm asking how would I control the volume of the headphones which inturn, would control the volumes of youtube and spotify.